# Object.values is not a function error

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot just to mess around with it and I am using express to create a website to control it. But I keep getting 'Object.values is not a function' when transferring to another page from a button click using this as the pug 'code'

`input(type="button", value="Turn bot off", onclick='window.location.href = "website";' ,id='offButton')`

Index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const DISCORD = require('discord.js');

const CLIENT = new DISCORD.Client();

const TOKEN = 'discord token';

//GET home page. 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Express'
  });
});

router.get('/off', function(req, res) {
  CLIENT.destroy();
  res.redirect('go back to home'); << where error is
});

CLIENT.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready')
});

CLIENT.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  } else if (message.content === 'off' && message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
    CLIENT.destroy();
  } else if (message.content.charAt(0) === '!') {
    message.channel.send('what?')
  }
});

CLIENT.login(TOKEN);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably upgrade your node.js. You need at least version 7.0.0 to have Object.values() supported. See https://node.green/#ES2017-features-Object-static-methods-Object-values